# Flutter plugin registrar.context() and registrar.activity() always null

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-plugin

I have been following a tutorial on creating a background service in flutter [Ben Konyi](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)

So what I am trying to get at is to be able to get the users location periodically. So what I have to do is make a plugin that will run a background service to do so. So in the constructor of the plugin class I have a `RealGeolocation(context: Context, and activity: Activity)...` which will be taken here:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    private val TAG = "RealGeolocation"

    @JvmStatic
    fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
      val plugin = RealgeolocationPlugin(registrar.context(), registrar.activity()) //the problem is here
      val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "plugins.flutter.io/realgeolocation")
      channel.setMethodCallHandler(plugin)
    }
}
//...
```

So when I try to build the project to run the example app in the project I get:

```
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.example.realgeolocation.RealgeolocationPlugin());
                                   ^
required: Context, Activity
found: no arguments
```

Please help!, it's been days going through the tutorial with no avail.

Comment: You found any solution?